# R plot y-axis tick bars at max and min

Tags: r, plot

I need to plot multiple plots of the same two variables but the range of y values differs across plots. To simplify the y axes, I would like each plot to show only show a tick mark and label at the min and max range on the y axis (min/max of the plot, not the data).

I've played around with the usr and yaxp parameters but no luck. Here's a toy example:

```
x<-1:10
y<-3:12
plot(x,y,yaxp=c(par("usr")[3],par("usr")[4],1))
```

I am expecting tick marks/labels corresponding to the top and bottom of the plot along the y axis (with none in-between) but this doesn't end up putting any tick marks or labels on the y axis. Can anyone explain why and how to return the desired outcome?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before the plotting actually occurs, the `usr` values won't be correct for your data.  One way to get correct values is to plot first, get the values, and then plot again using those values to place the tick marks:

```
plot(x, y)

min_tick <- par("usr")[3]
max_tick <- par("usr")[4]

plot(x, y, yaxt = "n") 
axis(side = 2, at = c(min_tick, max_tick))
```

[image]

I'm letting the default labeling occur.  That's something that can be customized as desired.

As @42 pointed out, the default plotting behavior for the axis is to extend the data range by 4%.  So, the min and max can be calculated using that information, as well:

```
min_tick <- min(y) - (max(y) - min(y)) * 0.04
max_tick <- max(y) + (max(y) - min(y)) * 0.04
```

Comment: R plotting typically extend the plot region a bit (I thought by  a factor of 1.04, but your example suggests it was 1.03) on either side of the min and max to allow points to be printed in full. You solution doesn't actually satisfy the OP's request that ticks be at the min and max of the values but instead has them at the min and max of the plot area.

Comment: @42 the OP said, "I would like each plot to show only show a tick mark and label at the min and max range on the y axis (min/max of the plot, not the data)."  Am I misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: No, but appears we did not share an understanding of what was requested. I didn't imagine that the OP understood that plot range was larger than the data range.

Comment: The increment above the max of 12:  `12 * 0.03 #[1] 0.36`

Comment: @42 my interpretation is that it is 1.04 * the data range:  `.04 * (12 - 3) = 0.36`

Comment: Ah. You're probably more perspicacious than I.

Comment: Thanks Jota, you had interpreted my question correctly: I wanted the ticks at the very top and bottom of the plot range, not the min and max of the data range.

Answer (score 2):

Just so it's here, the `ggplot2` equivalent is to set the `breaks` of `scale_y_continuous`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.frame(x, y), aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(min(y), max(y)))
```

[image: plot with y breaks at min and max]